# How to return Null in Case statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to return null value in case when. Here is my query

```
Declare @MasterProduct nvarchar(50) = N'Sharepoint Easy Nav',
        @ProductSlug nvarchar(50) = 'sharepoint-easynav-free',
        @CountryID bigint = 1111;

SELECT        
Product.ProductName, 
Product.MasterProductName, 
Price.ProductPrice, 
Price.ProductTax, 
Price.ProductTotalPrice, 
Product.TotalSiteCollectionText, 
Product.TotalSiteCollection, 
Product.Is_Support, 
Price.Is_Support_Price, 
Product.ProductSlug, 
Country.CountrySymbol, 
Country.CountryId
FROM
BR_Product as Product 
Inner Join BR_ProductPrice as Price on Product.ID = Price.ProductID 
left Join BR_Country as Country On Price.CountryID = Country.CountryId 
where Product.MasterProductName = IsNull(@MasterProduct, Product.MasterProductName) 
and Product.ProductSlug = IsNull(@ProductSlug, Product.ProductSlug) 
and Country.CountryId = case 
                          when (select count(BR_ProductPrice.ID) 
                                from BR_ProductPrice 
                                where  BR_ProductPrice.CountryID = @CountryID) > 0 
                          Then @CountryID 
                          else Null
                        end
```

It returns me no rows.
When I remove

> Country.CountryId = case when (select count(BR_ProductPrice.ID) from BR_ProductPrice where  BR_ProductPrice.CountryID = @CountryID) > 0 Then @CountryID else Null
> end

it Returns me following:
[image]

I want CountryId compare null part of case statement in else section something like this

> Then @CountryID else Country.CountryId is null

**Query is working properly when I pass CountryID = 1101.**

Comment: `select count(BR_ProductPrice.ID) 
                                from BR_ProductPrice 
                                where  BR_ProductPrice.CountryID = @CountryID` returns 1?

Comment: @Pream it returns me 0

Comment: Check if my answer below works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ISNULL(CountryID,'') on where conditions and on conditions and replace = null with = ''

```
Inner Join BR_ProductPrice as Price on Product.ID = Price.ProductID 
left Join BR_Country as Country On isnull(Price.CountryID,'') = isnull(Country.CountryId,'') 
where Product.MasterProductName = ISNULL(@MasterProduct, Product.MasterProductName) 
and Product.ProductSlug = ISNULL(@ProductSlug, Product.ProductSlug) 
and ISNULL(Country.CountryId,'') = case 
                      when (select count(BR_ProductPrice.ID) 
                            from BR_ProductPrice 
                            where  ISNULL(BR_ProductPrice.CountryID,'') = @CountryID) > 0 
                      Then @CountryID 
                      else ''
                    end
```

Comment: Work with charm.! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `=` with `null`. Try this instead:

```
and (
    (Country.CountryId = @CountryID 
     and (select count(BR_ProductPrice.ID) 
          from BR_ProductPrice 
          where  BR_ProductPrice.CountryID = @CountryID) > 0 
    ) 
    OR Country.CountryId IS NULL
    )
```

Comment: Yes but I pass correct ID 1101, it returns me both null and 1101 countryID. I just want only 1 value

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

from:

```
Country.CountryId = case 
                          when (select count(BR_ProductPrice.ID) 
                                from BR_ProductPrice 
                                where  BR_ProductPrice.CountryID = @CountryID) > 0 
                          Then @CountryID 
                          else Null
                        end
```

To:

```
Country.CountryId =(select Case when cnt_BR_ProductPriceID > 0 then @CountryID else null end from
(select count(BR_ProductPrice.ID) as cnt_BR_ProductPriceID from BR_ProductPrice where  BR_ProductPrice.CountryID = @CountryID) as cnt)
```

Never tried yet.

Hope it work.

Comment: I've tried same simulation the case when doesn't have any problem, It's just depend on your query above not in case when..